# Doctrine2 oneToMany relation yaml

Tags: php, mysql, yaml, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called “Object”, here is the yaml code:

```
Entities\Object:
  type: entity
  table: objects
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
      strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    parent_id: 
      type : integer
  oneToOne:
    type:
      targetEntity: ObjectType
      joinColumn:
        name: type_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I want to add a children parent relation (oneToMany) but I don’t know how? I want the mysql table to have following structure: id, type_id, parent_id and the entity to have those options $object->getParent() (single object) and $object->getChildren() (collection of objects) . 
Hope someone can help, thnx

Comment: So you want a self-referencing relationship, like how a category in a an e-commerce website could have a single parent category and multiple child categories?

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't think so much about how it will look in the database... just let Doctrine do it's thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to do One-to-Many, self referencing, it should be something like that:

```
Entities\Objects:
  type: entity
  table: objects
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  oneToMany:
    children:
      targetEntity: Objects
      mappedBy: parent
  manyToOne:
    parent:
      targetEntity: Objects
      inversedBy: children
      joinColumn:
        name: parent_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Take a look at the manual [Association Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: found it out after reading some more on the doc. anyway thnx a lot